# Brush tool texture for a painting app

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, textures, paint

Im working on a painting app which has a tool to brush similar to a painting brush. I've implemented so far through cocos2d, a format like the image

[image: the image]

.  But my client wants clear edged texture as the image

[image: the image]

Also the color of the former image is some what blurring indeed. How I can reduce blurring of the sprite image?  The image I am using as a texture is [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqZSi.png). Im using a code derived from the [Cocos2d RenderTextureTest](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/tests/RenderTextureTest.m?r=1325#46).

Also, the blend function Im using like in the below code

```
  [brush setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE, GL_ONE}];
  [brush.texture setAliasTexParameters];
```

where, brush is my sprite with the above mentioned texture.

Is there any other way to get the sharp edges as in the later image? Or how I can make the image stop blurring? I am struggling it for last few months. Please some experts look into this and help me.

Comment: Try to use [brush setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE }]; I hope it would be done.

Comment: @Marine, thanks for your reply, I tried that too, but the edge blurring still persists. Any other suggestions are welcomed.